# Access request object in next.config.js

Tags: next.js

I'm working on an application with a `next.config.js` file which sets a bunch of config variables to be used elsewhere in the application based on environmental variables. I want to add some more to this list based on the URL, I'm using the package `jekrb/next-absolute-url` to be able to read the URL.

The problem I'm having is in their example `const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req)` is used but I cannot get this to work in the `next.config.js` file. It just tells me that `req` is not defined.

Here's a cut down example of my current `next.config.js` file.

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withOffline = require('next-offline');
const compose = require('crocks/helpers/compose');
const absoluteUrl = require('next-absolute-url');

const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);

require('dotenv').config();

const injectedConfig = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    KEY: process.env.VALUE,
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    KEY: process.env.VALUE,
  },
}

module.exports = compose(
  withCSS,
  withFonts,
  withImages,
  withTM,
  withOffline
)(injectedConfig);
```

Comment: would you be able to give a specific example of those env vars based on URL? I wonder what problem you are trying to solve this way.

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko basically there are multiple URLs pointing towards the same container and a few of those environmental vars should be different depending on which URL it is being accessed from.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work cause this **"req"** object is actually a client request, that means it works only on **runtime**. `next.config.js` run at config time, therefore it is not available there.

You can use regular env variable, or `.env` file and load it with [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: That makes sense, I had realised this runs server side but had completely forgotten about this file not running at runtime. Will have to look at another way to alter these variables at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using a custom document:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const { pathname, query } = ctx;

    // having pathname and query, read config from elsewhere

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps, config: { pathname, query } };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <script
            id="config"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: JSON.stringify(this.props.config, null, 1)
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

in the `Document#getInitalProps` you can obtain current `pathname` and read corresponding config from somewhere, then render the config inside of a `<script>`. Though it looks hackish.
Also, it would require a custom `_app` to read the config from the `<script>` tag. In the `_app`, you could populate a React context with the config to be able to use it conveniently in other components.

**UPD**

Here is how you could use the stuff from `<script>` tag: create a custom app component, in `componentDidMount` get that element and parse the data from it, then use it as a context value.

```
import App from "next/app";
import React from "react";

export const ConfigContext = React.createContext({});

export default class MyApp extends App {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { config: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const config = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("config").textContent);
    this.setState({ config });
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <ConfigContext.Provider value={this.state.config}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ConfigContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

in your page component, you would be able to read it from the context:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { ConfigContext } from "./_app";

export default props => {
  const config = useContext(ConfigContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(config, null, 1)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

*And again, this issue seems to be a solution: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9524*

Comment: Tomoshenko Thanks for this and the code example but unless I'm mistaken the `JSON.stringify` doesn't output anything?

Comment: @NeilNand I've updated my answer with how you can use it